# nginx serve static file without ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx

for increment speed of my project, i want serve static file without ssl, problem is im very beginner with nginx, my actual nginx configuration is :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary on;

    server_name  selfmarket.net www.selfmarket.net;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/selfmarket.net/cert.pem;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/selfmarket.net/privkey.pem;    # path to your privkey.pem

    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
    fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

    # Serve static files and uploads
    location ^~ /static/ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        root /opt/master/app/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/';
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

in this moment i'm force all traffic in ssl, need change for static not use ssl. How i can do this ?

Comment: Serving some content over secure HTTPS and others via insecure HTTP will result in mixed content warnings for passive content (images) and errors for active content (scripts). Disabling HTTPS for static content is not  a way to gain performance benefits and will certainly cause other more severe issues around usability of your site.

Comment: +1 for @AnandBhat's comment. Also, if you compile your OpenSSL to the latest version and rebuild NGINX with this module, you should be able to deliver content over HTTP/2 which is faster* than raw HTTPS. *Not verified info, but check out this [link](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2015/01/16/a-simple-performance-comparison-of-https-spdy-and-http2/).